# Android placing multiple bitmaps in imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I have multiple ImageViews which are transparent and are meant to over lap one another. I am aligning then to one another but one problem presist. How can I set the order in which they are layered? Ive tried revising the code in both xml and how the images are set in the actual java code...

I have tried FrameLayout but maybe Im not using it right...here is my implementation:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".RadarActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_topo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_counties"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

No matter what I do...imageview_topo is always placed on top. Even in the code i have instantated topo first and retrieved its image first!

Thank you!

Comment: How about using FrameLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

I referred a site [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/) that says:

> If multiple child views exist, then they are drawn, in order, one atop
>   the other. This means that the first view added to the frame layout
>   will display on the bottom of the stack, and the last view added will
>   display on top.

You can check this site too: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

May be i can help you more if you show the screenshot of your UI.

Comment: Well what doesnt make sense is that I add the first image in my xml (topo) which should be the very bottom...its a solid image jpeg and then i add all my transparent gifs over it. But no matter what the jpeg topo covers the gifs? If i remove my jpeg topo then the images are displayed in order and are in view. But the jpeg is crucial in the whole setup!